# JBoss to Spring Boot and Spring Security upgrade: X509 Authentication problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

UPGRADING FROM: JBoss EAP 6.4 / Spring Security 4.2.1 (XML Configuration)

UPGRADING TO: Spring Boot 2.2.4 / Spring Security 5.2.1 (JavaConfig)

We have a REST endpoint protected by Spring Security that uses X509 authentication and a Test Client.

I breakpoint in **Spring Security's Filter Chain** at `X509AuthenticationFilter.extractClientCertificate`:

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request
        .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

I am no longer seeing the X509 Certificate coming across in the Request after going to Spring Boot and Spring Security 5.2 JavaConfig.

Didn't post source code because I don't expect anyone to fix my issue ... I'm just looking for some suggestions on where to dig or possible paths to explore.  Some thoughts ...

1. Does Spring Security in Spring Boot use the embedded Tomcat Connectors? If I have a Tomcat Connector for HTTPS and the client hits us on HTTPS, do I need to somehow tell the Tomcat Connector for HTTPS to extract the X509 Cert from the Request?
2. How or what puts the X509 Certificate into the Request with an attribute of `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`?  I was debugging against the old (working) JBoss EAP app and never could figure out how it got into the Request, only that it was there when I breakpoint in Spring Security's `X509AuthenticationFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone ever comes across this ... I resolved it and will be happy to answer questions if it helps others.

It turns out not to be an issue with Spring Security, but rather with how we had the Tomcat Connectors configured.

We needed to:

1. Set up the truststore for the Spring Boot Tomcat Secure Connector correctly, using the method calls below that are compatible with `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`.
2. Also (and this is essential) - setClientAuth to "true".

It's ugly, I dug into the source code for `Tomcat-embed-core`, but there are a series of strings that are the equivalent of "force the client to send the certificate as part of the Request".  Those strings are: "true", "yes", "require", "required".  They all do the same thing, so we just used "true".

```
    protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststorePath); // local directory path
    protocol.setTruststoreType(truststoreType); // a string of either PKCS12 or JKS
    protocol.setTruststorePass(truststorePass); // whatever password you set on your Keystore
    protocol.setClientAuth("true"); // Makes the client provide cert in Request over HTTPS
```

Tomcat Connectors are not well-documented.  There is a method call:

```
protocol.setSSLCACertificateFile(trustStorePath);
```

that does nothing under `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`.

Apparently it is meant to work with `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol` (Apache Portable Runtime).  That was a red herring for us, we made that method call, but it was not in fact setting up our truststore.